# Elliptical Curve Cryptography benchmark test

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves

I have built web app that implement Elliptical Curve Cryptography. During testing using data set that i chose on my own, it already run well..

But, for now, i want to test it in some benchmark test, just like AES that have some input, key, and expected cipher test..

is there any similar test for ECC? some program or web app, to test if my curve is valid, is my algorithm resulting the right cipher etc?

Thank you :)

Comment: Typically benchmarking is to assess speed.  You're looking for test vectors or known answer tests. Does your curve have a name?

Comment: i am looking for test vector @PaulUszak

Comment: You forgot to answer the last part of the question of Paul; that might be necessary if you want to have anything official. I've got a question of my own: what do you mean with *resulting the right cipher*? Which algorithm are you testing? Elliptic Curves can implement ElGamal and IES, but generally I don't think you'd start off testing those schemes...